# Passing properties to child component does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am trying to pass properties to a child component, but when I am trying to access them from within the child component, they are `undefined`.

I am creating a few forms and my idea was to create a parent component `LoginPanel` that is used by all forms, in this case `ResetForm`

**This is my parent component**

```
var LoginPanel = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
       return {status: false};
    },

    render() {

        // add props to children
        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
            (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
                status: this.state.status
            })
        );

        console.log(childrenWithProps[0]);
        // the new props (status) are copied, but previous properties (resetUrl) don't exist

        // this is the shortened html
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {childrenWithProps}
            </div>
        );
    }
})
```

**This is my child component**

```
var ResetForm = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("done:", this.props.status); // this.props.status is undefined
    },

    render()

        console.log("status:", this.props.status);  // this.props.status is undefined

        // shortened html
        return (
            <LoginPanel>
                <p>...</p>
            </LoginPanel>
        );
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ResetForm resetUrl={resetUrl}/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

**This is my console output**

```
status: undefined
child: Object {...}
done: undefined
```

I am also getting an error message from React in the console (I am actually trying to pass more properties, just restricted my example to the `status` property) but I don't understand what's the problem. The properties are unknown. Then how can I let React know about the props?

```
"Warning: Unknown props `statuses`, `status`, `message`, `updateStatus` on <form> tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see fb.me/react-unknown-prop
    in form (created by ResetForm)
    in div (created by LoginPanel)
    in div (created by LoginPanel)
    in div (created by LoginPanel)
    in LoginPanel (created by ResetForm)
    in ResetForm"
```

I already found other SO answers that explain how to pass props to child components and I tried to do the same. But apparently I am doing something wrong and I can't find the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: where are you having state status in your loginPanel

Comment: I actually did that. Just updated my question. I am also getting an error message from react. Added it to the end of my question. Do you know what that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turned out that when rendering the child component, the parent component has to be placed in the `ReactDOM.render()` function, not in the `render()` function of the component itself. This is how I fixed my child component:

```
var ResetForm = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("done:", this.props.status);
    },

    render()

        console.log("status:", this.props.status);

        // move <LoginPanel> from here ...
        return (
            <p>...</p>
        );
    }

});

ReactDOM.render(

    // ... to here
    <LoginPanel>
        <ResetForm resetUrl={resetUrl}/>
    </LoginPanel>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to make two corrections one in the `LoginPanel` you seem to have forgotten to define the `state status`. Include it as:

```
getInitialState: function() {
   return {status: false};
},
```

also include `getDefaultProps()` in your child component as

```
getDefaultProps: function() {
   return {state: null};
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I actually set the status in `getInitialState`, but didn't show it in my example. I added it for more clarity. Adding the properties to the child is working, but when I am using it in my `render` function, the props don't exist anymore when I'm trying to access them in my child component...